# Restrict Mode Line display to window

Tags: window, mode-line, window-splitting, powerline, exwm

I am configuring mode-line and currently the time is displayed in each window's mode-line, as shown by the image below. Is it possible to restrict the time display to the bottom right mode-line? 
[image]

Comment: Yes, but it would be a little complicated in terms of figuring out the position of each window during redisplay.  I have written up a couple of answers in the past that describe how to have different mode-lines depending upon which window is active, even though the buffer might be the same.  You need something more complicated than that which identifies window position relative to the frame.  The other problem is that `mode-lines` are not window-local per se, but rather buffer-local.